# TikZ/PGF: Simple function is not plotted. Where is the mistake?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm just starting to learn `TikZ/PGF`. I would like to draw a simple function, `f(x) = x²` to start with.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\draw [thick, domain=0:1] plot  (\x,  {\x*\x});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the most minimal example I can think of. Substituting the `\x*\x` with something else to exclude a syntax error does not work either. Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `\draw [thick, domain=0:1] plot (\x,{\x*\x});` to `\addplot [thick, domain=0:1]  (\x,{\x*\x});` and it should work fine

Comment: No worries, we all make simple mistakes at the beginning. And you'll learn more by it...Claudio's answer is probably more insightful though as it explains the mix up.

Answer (score 14):

I think you are mixing the syntax from both `TikZ` and `pgfplots`. Basically, if you want to use `pgfplots`, you need to call `\addplot` inside the `axis` environment, while when using `TikZ` you simply need the standard `\draw` command with `plot`.

Here you find two basic examples in both cases with your function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
Using just Ti\emph{k}Z:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ domain=0:1]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (1.9,1.9);
\draw [thick,] plot  (\x,\x*\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{2cm}
Using pgfplots:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1]
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Notice that in my example I just loaded `pgfplots` since it automatically loads `TikZ`.