# How to plot a quadratic equation in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following quadratic formula: $x^2-7x+10=0$ and I am trying to plot the curve by using the following script without success:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=15cm,
anchor=center,
]
\draw plot (x^2-7x+10=0) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You need the syntax `\addplot {x^2-7x+10};` for pgfplots. And you need a function not an equation.

Comment: Could you please have a look to [TikZ/PGF: Simple function is not plotted. Where is the mistake?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65691/13304) The problem looks similar. If that helps, we can consider to close this question as duplicate of the other.

Comment: @percusse `7*x`. lol

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: You can not plot equations(only functions) - this is Math - not LaTeX. It is not relevant that the function is quadratic. Plotting with TikZ and PGFPlots has been covered in several other questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
width=15cm,
anchor=center,
]
\addplot {x^2-7*x+10} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**NB:**

- your equation `x^2-7*x+10=0` corresponding to roots of the polynomial `x^2-7*x+10` (two points in fact)
- I think you want to plot the polynomial `x^2-7*x+10`
- you must write any mathematical operators (`^`, `*`,...)
- use `\addplot` (using `pgfplots`package).
- use `{` and `}`.

**Result:**
[image: rr]